# spring security error handling with JSON response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring security 3.1 and Spring 3.2 for REST services.
I'm struggling to make every response be JSON e.g. if user tries to access some resource but is not yet authenticated.
Also if user make wrong request I want to return JSON with error message.

Just to mention that would be more acceptible to have some global place where I should catch all errors/exceptions.

Comment: I am currently trying to figure this one out myself with the spring security portion. Find any solution to this yet? Ideally we want to have one error object defined in json for the client to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you write a controller class extended by all other controllers (or use @ControllerAdvice in case you are using 3.2) and include an exceptionhandler annotated method in that class? SOmething like this

```
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
public @ResponseBody GenericResponse handleException(Throwable throwable){
 //handle exception

 }
```

Or read this blog [post](http://www.baeldung.com/2013/01/31/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2/)

**UPDATE**

Sorry for this late reply. Here is my suggestion. Make it simply fail with a 403 response. For that just add the following snippet in your spring security configuration.

```
<beans:bean id="entryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />
```

and point entrypoint-ref to this bean

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="entryPoint">
```

And in the client side, in your AJAX code, add an error block

```
            error : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                if (jqXHR.status == 403){
                    alert('you need to login to do this operation');
                    window.location.href = contextPath+"/signin";
// or whatever you want to
                }
            }
```

Comment: doesn't solve my problem, doesn't catch wrong requests. Maybe is because of Spring security. Can't accept this answer as correct.

Comment: As Zemzela mentioned this does not take care of any issue around spring security as it throws exception or error before the controller is called.

Comment: @Michael: My bad, I missed the point that the authentication is done before the dispatcher servlet is invoked. I have updated my answer. Please give your insights.

Comment: How could be with a Java Class and without AJAX?

Comment: It has been a while since I worked on Spring. And right now I am a bit preoccupied with other work..